# rxjs 5.5+ retryWhen not calling source observable?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators, retrywhen

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here. I'm trying to create a simple retry for fetch but only the code in the `retryWhen` is getting executed. I'm using React so i dont have the `this.http.get` convenience. Perhaps it's an issue with `from(/*promise*/)`? I was trying to base the retry logic off of  [this post](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2018/06/21/retry-failed-http-calls-in-angular-6/).

This is what I would expect to see:

```
Getting data from fetch...
In the retryWhen
In the interval
/* repeat the previous 3 lines 3x times including the Fetch */
Giving up
```

Instead I get:

```
Getting data from fetch...
In the retryWhen
In the interval...
In the interval...
In the interval...
In the interval...
Giving up
```

So it is just repeating the code in he retryWhen interval but not repeating the original fetchData call. I'm probably missing something fundamental to my RXJS knowledge.

Here's the test code:

```js
const fetchData = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  console.log("Getting data from fetch...");
  rej(); // just fail immediately to test the retry
});

const source = from(fetchData)
  .pipe(
    retryWhen(_ => {
      console.log("In the retryWhen");
      return interval(1000).pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log("In the interval...")),
        flatMap(count => count == 3 ? throwError("Giving up") : of(count))
      )
    }));

source.subscribe(
  result => console.log(result),
  err => console.log(err)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the code below see if it works. `retryWhen` pass you a error stream which will keep emitting if there is error. you return a `timer` to specify the delay in between each retry inside `retryWhen`. After the delay it will retry the source observable for you

```
const fetchData = defer(() => new Promise((res, rej) => {
      console.log('in promise')
        rej("Failed to fetch data"); 
      // fail the first 2 times
    }) );

const source = fetchData.pipe(
  retryWhen(err => {
    let count = 0;
    console.log("In the retryWhen");
    return err.pipe(
      tap(_ => {
        count++;
        console.log("In the interval...");
      }),
      mergeMap(_ => (count == 2 ? throwError("Giving up") : timer(2000)))
    );
  })
);

source.subscribe(result => console.log(result), err => console.warn(err));
```

https://codepen.io/fancheung/pen/gqjawe

Comment: Thanks, I get the same result in console with the modified code though. I have created a stackblitz to show the results: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-us8viy

Comment: Here is an even more simple example that doesn't work. It's just a simple `retry` that doesn't ever retry. What am I missing here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hfcdyq

Comment: Forgot to change to defer, promise will execute immediately and won't get repeated. updated the answer.